# How to input images to Azure IOT Hub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I a new to Azure and I have an application where i have to send an image from a device to azure IOT which in turns goes to Azure cognitive services and processes the image for required result.

I have been looking around the internet for options and have seen that using raspberry pi i can achieve this , I want to know is this achievable using an API. Is it possible for me to upload an image into Azure IOT hub by using an .net API (simulating device), if so please suggest relative techniques or please let me know if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the Azure IoT Hub supports the following techniques for your solution described in the following docs:

- [Upload files with IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload)
- [IoT Hub Device Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-streams-overview) (preview)